# Slideshow stacked with menu

Tags: slideshow, stacked

problem link : http://comingsoonnurul.blogspot.com/
why did the Slideshow stacked with menu??

html:

```
<div id="cf4a" class="shadow" >
  <img= src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg">
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Turtle.jpg">
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Rainbow%20Worm.jpg">
  <img src="http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/images/Birdman.jpg">
</div>
```

css:

```
#cf4a {
  position:absolute;
}

#cf4a img {
  position:absolute;
   height:105px;
  width:200px;
 left:0;
}
```